Flutter Always-Visible Notification When App is Closed (Android 14)
I am building a music player app in Flutter and need to implement a persistent notification that:

Always remains visible, even when the app is closed or in the background.
Is compatible with Android 14.

I have tried using the flutter_background_service and flutter_local_notifications packages, but I'm encountering some challenges with Android 13/14 notification permissions and foreground services.
What I’ve Done
Here’s the relevant code I’ve implemented so far:

Initialize Foreground Service

Future<void> initializeService() async {
final service = FlutterBackgroundService();

const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
  'music_player_channel',
  'Music Player Service',
  description: 'This channel is used for persistent music player notifications.',
  importance: Importance.high,
);

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
 const InitializationSettings(
   android: AndroidInitializationSettings('ic_launcher'),
   iOS: DarwinInitializationSettings(),
 ),
);

await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
  .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
      AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
  ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

 await service.configure(
  androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
    onStart: onStart,
    autoStart: true,
    isForegroundMode: true,
    notificationChannelId: 'music_player_channel',
    initialNotificationTitle: 'Music Player',
    initialNotificationContent: 'Playing in the background',
    foregroundServiceNotificationId: 1,
  ),
  iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
    autoStart: true,
    onForeground: onStart,
  ),
 );
}


Foreground Service Handler

void onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
  DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();

  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
    service.on('stopService').listen((event) {
      service.stopSelf();
    });

    if (await service.isForegroundService()) {
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        1,
        'Music Player',
        'Playing your favorite music',
        const NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            'music_player_channel',
            'Music Player Service',
            icon: 'ic_launcher',
            ongoing: true,
            autoCancel: false,
            importance: Importance.high,
            priority: Priority.high,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}


List item

I’ve added the following permissions to AndroidManifest.xml:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />

I’m also requesting runtime permissions using permission_handler:
Future<void> requestPermissions() async {
  if (await Permission.notification.isDenied) {
    await Permission.notification.request();
  }
}

Issue
The notification works when the app is running, but:

It doesn't appear consistently when i swiper then notification is removed.

How can I ensure:

The notification is always visible (even when the app is closed)?
The app is compliant with Android 14 requirements?

Any guidance, examples, or best practices would be appreciated!
